# Send mail via smtp.office365.com using other email address as the FROM address

Tags: vb.net, email, smtp, office365, system.net.mail

I want to sending email through smtp.office365.com in VB.NET
It work!! when i use "FROM" address same as user authentication

BUT how to send emails using other email address as the FROM address in domain

I try "Mailbox Delegation" set other email address for behalf
BUT it don't work. Please suggest where I'm going wrong.

I am using the following to

```
Dim myMessage As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
Dim myClient As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient()

Dim strUserName As String = "john@domain.com"
Dim strPassword As String = "p@ssw0rd"

myClient.Port = 587
myClient.Host = "smtp.office356.com"
myClient.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(strUserName, strPassword)
myClient.EnableSsl = True

myMessage.From = New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("marry@domain.com")
myMessage.To.Add(strTo)
myMessage.Subject = "Send E-mail using Office365"
myMessage.Body = "Test Send Email"

myClient.Send(myMessage)
```

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: Hi @Bruce ,I have error message like this   " Transaction failed. The server response was: 5.2.0 STOREDRV.Submission.Exception
:SendAsDeniedException.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied;
Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message 
Cannot submit message. ..., 20.52176:140FE2841800101082010000"  please suggest.

Comment: I can solved this problem with 'Mailbox Delegation'